# PHP - Get HTML Form Submission, put any checked Checkboxes into an unordered html list on PHP page

Tags: php, html-lists

Working on a course, and I'm struggling with making this happen. Basically, I want to have a bunch of checkboxes, that when checked are read by a php page and then displayed in an unordered html list. For instance, a pizza order form. Select what toppings are wanted, and then submit the form. It then returns the page saying what you ordered.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Pizza Order Form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="processform.php">
        <h3>Toppings:</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Pepperoni" name="Toppings" value="Pepperoni">
        <label for="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sausage" name="Toppings" value="Sausage">
        <label for="Sausage"> Sausage</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Bacon" name="Toppings" value="Bacon">
        <label for="Bacon"> Bacon</label><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP Page

```
<?php

$Toppings = $_POST['Toppings'];
if(empty($Toppings)) {
    echo "No Toppings Selected";
}   else {
    print_r($Toppings);
    foreach($Toppings as $Topping) {
        echo $Topping;
    }
    $ToppingList = implode(',', $Toppings);
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pretend Pizza Purchase:</h1>
        <h2> Order Details</h2>
        <?php echo '<ul>';
            foreach($ToppingList as $Topping)
            {
                echo '<li>';
                echo $Topping;
                echo'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for php to consider your checkbox elements as an array, you have to add braces to their names like so

`name=Toppings[]`

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

If the input is a checkbox, then there must be [] at the end of the attribute name. Otherwise, `$_POST['Toppings']` is the last option selected.
For example, the user selects Pepperoni and Sausage, then `$_POST['Toppings']` is Sausage.

### Function `[]`

When the form is submitted, `$_POST['Toppings']` will be treated as an array, and you can manipulate the array.

## Answer

### HTML

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Pizza Order Form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="processform.php">
        <h3>Toppings:</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Pepperoni" name="Toppings[]" value="Pepperoni">
        <label for="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sausage" name="Toppings[]" value="Sausage">
        <label for="Sausage"> Sausage</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Bacon" name="Toppings[]" value="Bacon">
        <label for="Bacon"> Bacon</label><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

### PHP Page

```php
<?php

$Toppings = $_POST['Toppings'];
if(empty($Toppings)) {
    echo "No Toppings Selected";
}   else {
    print_r($Toppings);
    foreach($Toppings as $Topping) {
        echo $Topping;
    }
    $ToppingList = implode(',', $Toppings);
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pretend Pizza Purchase:</h1>
        <h2> Order Details</h2>
        <?php echo '<ul>';
            foreach($Toppings as $Topping)
            {
                echo '<li>';
                echo $Topping;
                echo'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```